# Any way to add more GPIOs to the AIY Voice Kit?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, pigpio

I'm working on a project using the google AIY Voice Kit V2 as a base. I'm planning on adding a keypad which requires 12 GPIOs. Does anyone know of a way to add more GPIOs to the Pi Zero W with AIY Voice Kit?

Comment: why does a keypad require 12 data lines?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a break-out board like the [Black HAT Hacker](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/mini-black-hat-hack3r) or [Pico HAT Hacker](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pico-hat-hacker).

Alternatively, connect another Pi Zero as a USB gadget and use the [GPIO expander](https://bennuttall.com/raspberry-pi-zero-gpio-expander/).